# Euler theorem and order of an element

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

We know that if $gcd(a, 11.13)=1$ then by Euler theorem $a^{120} \equiv 1$ mod(11.13). Then my questions are the following.

1. How can one shows that a stronger result is true, that is if $gcd(a, 11.13)=1$ then $a^{60} \equiv 1$ mod(11.13)?
2. How to show $60$ is the tight result. That is show that for all $1 \leq n < 60$ there exists an $a$ with $gcd(a, 11.13)=1$ and $a^n$ not congruent to $1$ mod(11.13)?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanking you.

Comment: Chinese Remainder Theorem. Work mod 11, then mod 13, then combine results.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Hello Sir! Can you please write the solution for me?

Comment: I can, but I'd rather you write it for yourself. Let's start at the beginning. Do you know what the Chinese Remainder Theorem is?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Let $x = a \; mod(p)$ and $x = b \; mod(q)$ Then $x = something \;  mod(pq).$

Answer (score 1):

As Gerry said just use the Chinese Remainder Theorem and the Euler Totient Theorem. More explicitly we have that $a^{10} \equiv 1 \pmod {11} \implies a^{60} \equiv (a^{10})^6 \equiv 1^6 \equiv 1 \pmod {11}$. Similalry we have that $a^{12} \equiv 1 \pmod {13} \implies a^{60} \equiv (a^{12})^5 \equiv 1^5 \equiv 1 \pmod{13}$. Combining these two claims by the Chinese Remaidner Theorem we have that $a^{60} \equiv 1 \pmod {11}$.

On the other side to prove that $60$ is the minimal number note that $n$ has to be a divisor of $60$ first of all. Assume that such $n<60$ exists. Then just take some $a$ such that $a^{\gcd(n,10)} \not \equiv 1 \pmod {11}$ or $a^{\gcd(n,12)} \not \equiv 1 \pmod {13}$. Note that such $a$ always exists as $LCM[10,12] = 60$, so either $\gcd(n,10) \not = 10$ or $\gcd(n,12) \not = 12$. But as the multiplicative groups modulo $11$ and $13$ are cyclic, an element of order $10$ or $12$, respectively must exists.

Anyway if you're more interested you can check the [Carmichael Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function), which gives a nice formula to calculate the Carmichael Number, or the so called *least universal exponent function*. And as you might guess the Carmichael number for $11 \cdot 13 = 143$ is $60$.